# Revoking default permission fails in new Office 365 Group

Tags: permissions, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

After a file is uploaded to an Office 365 Group’s OneDrive using the Graph API, we want to revoke the default permissions on the file. However, in groups which have only recently be created, this fails.

By default, a file's permissions are “*GroupName* Owners”, “*GroupName* Members” and “*GroupName* Visitors”. We want to remove these permissions and grant access to specific AD Security Groups.

After uploading a file we are seeing two different results when getting the default permissions (in preparation to delete them).

In one case, we get four permissions – the three listed above, plus a ‘special’ permission which has **grantedTo** with a user with id matching the group id. We have learned not to delete this permission, as we lose the ability to delete the other permissions.

Here, this ‘special’ permission is the first one listed:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$metadata#drives('b%21Y25ow5oitkOvNToutf7LrYZ-y78P2jBEjoGLzb3oPqnw0a3YKFDwTobjTB4gYxKt')/root/permissions",
"value": [
    {
        "grantedTo": {
            "user": {
                "id": "273c2c33-8533-445d-ae65-4b63be296995",
                "displayName": "SharePoint Tests"
            }
        },
        "id": "Yzowby5jfGZlZGVyYXRlZGRpcmVjdG9yeWNsYWltcHJvdmlkZXJ8MjczYzJjMzMtODUzMy00NDVkLWFlNjUtNGI2M2JlMjk2OTk1X28",
        "roles": [
            "write"
        ]
    },
    {
        "grantedTo": {
            "user": {
                "displayName": "SharePoint Tests Owners"
            }
        },
        "id": "U2hhcmVQb2ludCBUZXN0cyBPd25lcnM",
        "roles": [
            "SP.Full Control",
            "write"
        ]
    },
    {
        "grantedTo": {
            "user": {
                "displayName": "SharePoint Tests Visitors"
            }
        },
        "id": "U2hhcmVQb2ludCBUZXN0cyBWaXNpdG9ycw",
        "roles": [
            "read"
        ]
    },
    {
        "grantedTo": {
            "user": {
                "displayName": "SharePoint Tests Members"
            }
        },
        "id": "U2hhcmVQb2ludCBUZXN0cyBNZW1iZXJz",
        "roles": [
            "SP.Edit"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However, for a period after the group has been created, after uploading a file, we only get 3 permissions back – the special one mentioned above is missing. In this case, trying to delete the other permissions fail with an ‘unauthenticated’ error code. E.g.

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/drives/b!zn7l0OHTmUa3lGABIbIGQIZ-y78P2jBEjoGLzb3oPqnw0a3YKFDwTobjTB4gYxKt/items/013LUA5IQEPURED3OSURAI27FBHDYLFQJP/permissions/U2FnZSAtIFBBUiBTZWN1cml0eSA0IE93bmVycw
```

We can still *add* permissions, just not revoke the default ones.

This condition seems to persist for all files created within a given Office 365 Unified Group until several minutes after it has been created.

Our only option at the moment looks to be to create a dummy file, and see if we get 3 or 4 permissions back (or just try deleting the default permissions). If we only get 3 try again after some time period. But this seems like a fragile hack, and adds significant time (several minutes) to our upload process.

Does anyone have any better suggestions, or an explanation of this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: update - in our most recent tests this morning, we found it was 64 minutes after the group was created that permissions could be revoked.

Answer (score 1):

Peter, Groups files are stored in a SharePoint document library and hence permissions (owners & members) are inherited from the AzureAD and cannot be changed, see this documentation for more information: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: thanks Christophe, but those permissions can indeed be revoked, as I said in my question. The problem is that it only works after a period of time after creating the group.

Comment: Peter this is not a supported scenario. What scenario/use case are you trying to achieve? If you want to modify who are the groups members in a SharePoint document library please use the Groups REST API to do so.

Comment: Hi @christophe-fiessinger Why is this not a supported scenario? It is possible through the SharePoint UI - go into the group's OneDrive, right-click the file, choose Details --> Sharing --> Advanced, then you can revoke the default permissions. I'm not trying to modify the *members* of the group, rather control which files existing members have *permission* to access.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break inheritance and please see these additional features we are rolling specific to the SharePoint document library: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/UPDATE-Create-Office-365-Groups-with-team-sites-from-SharePoint/m-p/48277